# Javascript countdown missing an event when it reach zero

Tags: javascript, dom-events, getelementbyid, countdown

Trying to make a message show when time arrived to 0 and for a few hours, as a week contains 594000 seconds, I would like the the message "it's time for beer" to be shown when var "secs" is bigger than 594000 seconds (so it will show the message from 4PM on friday to about 7PM as the counter reset at 4PM and secs will be between 604800 and 594000 secs.

The function I created ALERTB doesn't seem to show the message. I am new to Javascript, tried to search and need help if possible, probably doing a simple error...

```
  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">

var cday;
var timeInSecs;
var ticker;

function getSeconds() {
    var now = new Date();
    var nowtime = now.getTime(); // time now in milliseconds
    var countdowntime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 16, 0, 0); //  16 hrs = 4 pm
    // countdowntime - change time hh,mm,ss to whatever time required, e.g. 7,50,0 (0750)

    var dy = 5; // Friday (day 5) - change for other days 0-6
    var atime = countdowntime.getTime();
    var diff = parseInt((atime - nowtime) / 1000); // positive if date is in future
    if (diff > 0) {
        cday = dy - now.getDay();
    } else {
        cday = dy - now.getDay() - 1;
    }
    if (cday < 0) {
        cday += 7;
    } // aleady passed countdown time, so go for next week
    if (diff <= 0) {
        diff += (86400 * 7)
    }
    startTimer(diff);
}



function startTimer(secs) {
    timeInSecs = parseInt(secs);
    ticker = setInterval("tick()", 1000);
    tick(); // to start counter display right away
}

function alertb() { // PROBLEMATIC, DOESN'T SHOW 
    var secs = timeInSecs;
    while (secs > 0) {}
    document.getElementById("hb").innerHTML = "it's beer time !!!";
}

function tick() {
    var secs = timeInSecs;
    if (secs > 0) {
        timeInSecs--;
    } else {
        clearInterval(ticker); // stop counting at zero
        getSeconds(); // and start all over again! 
    }

    var days = Math.floor(secs / 86400);
    secs %= 86400;
    var hours = Math.floor(secs / 3600);
    secs %= 3600;
    var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    secs %= 60;
    var result = "Time remaining " + cday + ' day(s) ';
    result += ((hours < 10) ? "0" : "") + hours + " hours " + ((mins < 10) ? "0" : "") + mins + " minutes " + ((secs < 10) ? "0" : "") + secs + " seconds";
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = result;
}



</script>
</head>

<body onload = "getSeconds()">
<div id="maindiv" class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
    <div id="title-countdown">
        <span class="bchewy col-lg-12" id="title">It's time for beer in ...</span>
    </div>
    <div id="container-countown">
        <span id="countdown" class="schewy col-lg-12"> </span>
        <span id="hourb" class="rchewy col-lg-12"> </span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: WTH do you include jQuery if you don't use it? Also, you don't seem to include the [tag:jquery-countdown] plugin at all?

Comment: Your `alertb()` function is never called, so it won't do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your alertb() function doesn't do anything - it enters a while loop `while (secs>0)` but then never changes the value in secs. So it will go on waiting for secs to change, forever, never exiting the loop.